# How to remove scroll for anchor tag hash click in javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am using wordpress visual composer tabs in my wordpress theme, I am also using same tab menus in Wordpress main menu with hastags like #mylink. When I click on that anchor tag in menu I given page reload option. But before page reload it is scrolling down for it's related content of that tab content.
Here is the code that I am using

```
$('.sub-menu .menu-item a').click(function(e) {
     location = this.href;
      location.reload(true);

    });
```

I want to remove the scroll when you click on the the hashed anchor tag.

for reference URL: http://wtastudios.com/novus2/projectsservices/#solar_Rooftops

Comment: Have u tried `e.preventDefault(); ` ?

Comment: Simply remove this script hope its working fine and also remove # tag from the menu.

Comment: I using tabs in that page? http://wtastudios.com/novus2/projectsservices/#solar_Rooftops

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).on('click','.sub-menu .menu-item a',function(e) {
if($(this).attr('href')).indexOf('#') > -1){
//return false;
e.preventDefault();
}

});
```

dont use clik() anymore, on is better, because it is been trigger even after document.ready.

then you must target only href that contains #.

Comment: if($(this).attr).indexOf('#') > -1){ saying Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .

Comment: You need to attract the href parameter: `if($(this).attr('href').indexOf('#') > -1){}`

Comment: ya I have added that. Please check http://wtastudios.com/novus2/projectsservices/#solar_Rooftops